# Can't locate object method "SSL_ca_file"

Tags: perl, sockets, ssl, methods

I'm trying to work through a SSL example from [IO::Socket::SSL at CSPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.38/SSL.pm).

I added `SSL_ca_file` to the example:

```
$client->SSL_ca_file('ca-rsa-cert.pem')
        || die "failed to set CA certificate";
```

When I attempt to execute the script, I get:

```
Can't locate object method "SSL_ca_file" via package "IO::Socket::SSL"
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Google is not turning up useful responses.

**EDIT**: when I try to use Miller's suggestion below:

```
my $client = IO::Socket::SSL->new("example.com:8443",
        SSL_ca_file => 'ca-rsa-cert.pem')
        || warn "I encountered a problem: ".IO::Socket::SSL::errstr();
```

I receive an error:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/IP.pm line 328.
I encountered a problem: IO::Socket::IP configuration failed error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0) at ./TestCert.pl line 6.
```

**EDIT**: followed the docs provided by Miller, everything worked fine:

```
my $client = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
        PeerAddr => 'example.com',
        PeerPort => '8443',
        Proto    => 'tcp',
        SSL_ca_file => 'ca-rsa-cert.pem')
        || warn "I encountered a problem: ".IO::Socket::SSL::errstr();
```

The system is Debian Wheezy (7.3, x64). PERL is version 5.14.2.

Comment: If you look at the usage example right at the top of the documentation you will find the proper use of SSL_ca_file.

Comment: Steffen - Under synopsis? That's what I used as a base project/program (and cited the reference). But the usage example did not include `SSL_ca_file`.

Comment: yes, in the synopsis: http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.969/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm - and these parameters are even commented in the example in the synopsis.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's a more complete example. I wish I would have stumbled across it first. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SSL_ca_file` is an available option to the `new` constructor for [`IO::Socket::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL).   It's not an available method.

```
my $client = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    SSL_ca_file => 'ca-rsa-cert.pem',
) or warn "I encountered a problem: ".IO::Socket::SSL::errstr();
```

I've never needed to use this module before, but docs state that there are examples in the [`example directory`](https://metacpan.org/source/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.969/example) of the package if that helps.

Comment: Yes, the missing quote was a typo.  Fixed.